# ili9341 2.4" Stopped Working on specific ESP32 board

Tags: arduino, lcd, esp8266, esp32

made esp32 board with ILI9341 2.4" LCD.
it was working for the past few days and all of sudden LCD stopped working as start showing as in image.

I tried connecting the LCD with ESP32 DEVKIT V1 with some sample code the LCD works fine.

What could be the reason.?

Library I'm Using **"TFT_eSPI.h"**

PINS USED

```
#define TFT_MISO 19
#define TFT_MOSI 23
#define TFT_SCLK 18
#define TFT_CS   15  // Chip select control pin
#define TFT_DC    2  // Data Command control pin
#define TFT_RST   4  // Reset pin (could connect to RST pin)
#define TOUCH_CS 5     // Chip select pin (T_CS) of touch screen
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: and my question is what could be the reason for the weird behavior

Comment: So it doesn't work on your ESP32, but does work on the Dev Kit? That sounds like (and from your image looks like too) a problem with your code running on the ESP32. I'll almost guarantee that this is not a hardware problem.

Comment: I don't the DW01 circuit protects the battery at all. No battery current flows via the disconnection FET, both charging and discharging currents seem to bypass the protection. Also, are the GND symbol with text same node as GND symbol without text? You are also connecting chips powered from greater than 3.3V to the MCU that can't handle IO voltages beyond 3.3V range. You are also charging the RTC battery and it is not a chargeable battery. The resistors are also too large to run the RTC with battery. Maybe you just have a loose connection or don't send a reset or something.

Comment: thanks... 
all the ground nodes are same (with and without label)
yes... RTC and MLX are powered by 5v. does that make problem to the board?

Comment: Yes it is a problem if you have pull-ups to 5V and the MCU IO pins are not 5V tolerant. If you change pull-ups to 3.3V, then chips running at 5V may fail to detect 3.3V as valid logic level.